# DatabaseExecutionContext is missing from the Play API

Tags: scala, playframework

I am following the DB presription provided [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase). However, the class DatabaseExecutionContext is nowhere near to be found in the play API and, hence, I am unable to import it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example code here: https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-scala-anorm-example/app/models/DatabaseExecutionContext.scala

```
import javax.inject._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext

@Singleton
class DatabaseExecutionContext @Inject()(system: ActorSystem) extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "database.dispatcher")
```

You need to configure this context as shown by the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Using-a-CustomExecutionContext

Comment: While this works, it's usually better to keep the execution context as a trait, so that you can write tests without depending on akka.

Comment: The "u need to configure this context" part was the key to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you already got an answer, I suggest to use a base trait instead, like:

```scala
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait DatabaseExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class DatabaseAkkaExecutionContext @Inject()(system: ActorSystem)
    extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "database.dispatcher")
    with DatabaseExecutionContext
```

The reason is that if you don't, you'll need to bring akka while testing operations requiring this execution context, with the trait, you should be able to write a simple executor for your tests, like:

```scala
  implicit val globalEC: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

  implicit val databaseEC: DatabaseExecutionContext = new DatabaseExecutionContext {
    override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = globalEC.execute(runnable)

    override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = globalEC.reportFailure(cause)
  }
```

**EDIT**: I have created a detailed [post](https://wiringbits.net/scala/playframework/2020/03/22/notes-about-play-framework-and-the-execution-context.html) explaining this.